# Mac wakes up after a few seconds: System Wake Reason not found

Tags: sleep-wake, catalina, airport

For the last few weeks I've run into issues with my 2017 MacBook Air on macOS Catalina `10.15.1`. (Edit: it also happens on `10.15.2` and `10.15.3`.)

Whenever I go tell it to sleep (either through closing the lid or the context menu or CMD + Shift + Q) it wakes up after about 2 seconds.

I've already tried the following things with no avail:

1. Reset SMC
2. Reset NVRAM
3. Boot into safe mode
4. Disconnect any devices
5. Log into another user
6. Disable wifi
7. Disable waking up the mac from lid opening
8. Disable hibernation
9. Disable boot on lan

I've got the following log outputs

`pmset -g assertions`:

```
2020-01-19 23:19:43 +0100 
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
pid 133(powerd): [0x000009910009a039] 00:00:01 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.powermanagement.wakeschedule"  
    Timeout will fire in 0 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease

# This line is repeated with incrementing hex numbers within the 
# brackets literally thousands of times

Timeout will fire in 2 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 176(hidd): [0x0000002600098dfc] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:100000337 name:AppleHIDKeyboardEve product:Apple Internal Keyb eventType:3"  
    Timeout will fire in 120 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
No kernel assertions.
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

And `log show | grep -i "Wake reason"` (shortened):

```
2020-01-19 23:12:44.154039+0100 0x3a0      Default     0x0                  204    0    airportd: systemWokenByWiFi: System Wake Reason not found
2020-01-19 23:12:44.154170+0100 0x3a0      Default     0x0                  204    0    airportd: systemWokenByWiFi: System Wake Reason not found
2020-01-19 23:12:44.154277+0100 0x3a0      Default     0x0                  204    0    airportd: systemWokenByWiFi: System Wake Reason not found
2020-01-19 23:12:44.240592+0100 0x5dbc     Default     0x0                  204    0    airportd: systemWokenByWiFi: System Wake Reason not found
```

Activity monitor shows kernel_task with by far the most idle wakeups but that bit of information seems somewhat useless

Comment: are there any entries in `pmset -g log`, around the times that it wakes?

Comment: this is a shot in the dark, but did you try upgrading to 10.15.2? maybe there are fixes in that update?

Comment: Do you have you mac plugged into an external monitor?

Comment: @Theologin it happens both with a monitor plugged in and without

Comment: @intagli sadly that did not fix the issue

Comment: @vykor I don't seem to be able to find any timestamps in its output.. The last line however, is "Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler"

Comment: Any luck on this? I've been having this issue for months and it's driving me insane. My terminal output is similar to yours

Comment: @Shivam Sinha Fixed it by reinstalling on a completely new SSD. (Probably a full system reinstall would've sufficed but I wanted to upgrade my storage either way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a clean install of MacOS and it completely solved the issue.

Just to be clear, I deleted EVERYTHING off the hard drive and re-installed MacOS. So basically it was a software issue.

I went through everything on Apple’s website to isolate the problem. Finally called Apple support who worked with me for 1-2hrs. Then finally just recommended a clean install. And bam, fixed.